# Can we pray 45 degrees left or 45 degrees right from original qibla direction ?

Tags: salat, qiblah

I read somewhere that we can pray 45 degrees left or 45 degrees right from original qibla direction. Is this right ?

Comment: Hearsay is a bad source of knowledge. See for example https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/31334/facing-the-qiblah-during-salah or https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/43752/how-accurate-does-east-direction-need-to-be? or https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/10286/qibla-tolerance ,,, we have plenty of questions and answers on this topic.

Answer (score 2):

Read my answer on [Facing the Qiblah during salah](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/31334/facing-the-qiblah-during-salah)?

You should know that my understanding of the quotes of that answer is that if you knew the direction of the qiblah you should stick to it else you will be sinning!

But in case you have no possibility to find out the qiblah and did ijtihad by for example jduging via the position of the son etc. and missed it by 45° it is accepted, but missing it intentionally is a sin.